# how do I clear the developer tools log console in safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, console

I'm using this code successfuly in IE, FF and Chrome, but Safari throws an error on console.clear. Is there a way to do this in Safari?

```
if (window.console && console.log)
{
    console.clear();
    console.log("console cleared");
}
```

Comment: I don't have Safari by me right now but type console.__proto__ into the console to see all of it's methods

Comment: no such thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing like that, sadly. Use ⌘+K to clear it "by hand" (or console.log some newlines ;).)